# How to edit Twitter Bootstrap Dashboard Template using WAMP

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, wamp

I am trying to make a dashboard myself. I copy paste Bootstrap and theme files into WAMP directory and when I load it, it just gives a page without images and all. What is the best way for me too create a GUI using WAMP for Web backend Dashboard ?

Comment: what do you mean "without images and all" .. what is all ?

Comment: If you check the Dashboard example template available in Bootstrap, may be not images there will green circle icons which and decent alignment. In my case it just comes all misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you forgot to change the href's of the links and javascript tags.

You will need to adjust the style sheet and javascript links to match where you put them on your server.

Comment: What I did was unzip bootstrap files which has 3 folders css, js and fonts and put them into my WAMP folder. And downloaded the example theme and put the html and CSS file on the same folder. And when I use localhost/dashboard it get this page but not what I saw in example.